# Angular - pipe and elvis operator (?) causes getter to be called sooner

Tags: angular

I have came across a strange case which I don't understand.
When I use a pipe and elvis operator, the code is executed in different part of lifecycle.

Having this simplified situation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class FooComponent {
  @Input() foo: any;

  get bar() {
    console.log('bar getter called, this.foo:', this.foo);
    return this.foo;
  }
}
```

If I use it like this:

```
  <app-foo #fooComponent [foo]="{a:1}">
    <span [title]="(fooComponent.bar | somePipe)?.a"></span>
  </app-foo>
```

the `bar` getter is called when `foo` attribute was not filled yet (it is undefined).
Console: `bar getter called, this.foo: undefined`

In any other usages:

```
<span [title]="fooComponent.bar?.a"></span>
<span [title]="(fooComponent.bar | somePipe).a"></span>
<span title="{{(fooComponent.bar | somePipe)?.a}}"></span>
```

it works as expected.
Console: `bar getter called, this.foo: {a: 1}`

Can anyone explain this? Is it intention? Or BUG?

**UPDATE:**

problem is gone after update from Angular 10.0 to Angular 10.2

Comment: please post also the pipe so we can claim issues

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wz842t?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: the pipe was not important, it was doing also with ‘async’ pipe